# history.pushState URL interaction with jquery load causing page fetch failure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-history

I'm using [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to set a URL, while at the same time using a jquery [.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to actually load the page content. I'm new to the history API, but I understand that this is the normal way to get back-button/etc functionality in dynamic sites.

The problem is that the spoofed address I'm setting with `pushState` is being used by `.load` in some way when it fetches pages, which means that `.load` is trying to fetch non-existant pages, and so fails. `DocumentRoot` is at `/var/www/bar` on the server. In this example, the user is attempting to navigate between two points in a single html file on the server, which is located at `dir1/dir2/p1.html` under `DocumentRoot` on the server.

1. When the user clicks on link 1, the server should return `dir1/dir2/p1.html #Container1`, and the address bar should show `foo.com/a/b/c`
2. When the user clicks on link 2, the server should return `dir1/dir2/p1.html #Container2`, and the address bar should show `foo.com/a/b/d`

So how exactly do I do this? This is what I've tried with relative URLs, and it fails:

```
$("#mainContent").load("dir1/dir2/p1.html #container1");  // good: XHR fetch foo.com/bar/dir1/dir2/p1.html
history.pushState(null, null, "a/b/c");                   // good: shows 'foo.com/a/b/c' as the URL
...
$("#mainContent").load("dir1/dir2/p1.html #container2");  // bad: XHR fetch foo.com/bar/a/b/dir1/dir2/p1.html
history.pushState(null, null, "a/b/d");                   // bad: shows 'foo.com/a/b/a/b/d' as the URL
```

And this is what happens when I use absolute URLs:

```
$("#mainContent").load("/dir1/dir2/p1.html #container1");  // good: XHR fetch foo.com/bar/dir1/dir2/p1.html
history.pushState(null, null, "a/b/c");                    // good: shows 'foo.com/a/b/c' as the URL
...
$("#mainContent").load("/dir1/dir2/p1.html #container2");  // bad: XHR fetch foo.com/a/b/dir1/dir2/p1.html
history.pushState(null, null, "a/b/d");                    // good: shows 'foo.com/a/b/d' as the URL
```

Note that the absolute paths are even worse, in that the XHR fetches don't even use `DocumentRoot` (`bar`) any more. Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

relative case tested on Chrome/Windows and Firefox/Linux with the same results; absolute case tested only on Firefox/Linux.

**EDIT 2**

I've been experimenting and found two ways to fix this, but I don't really understand what's going on, so I won't post this as an answer:

1. Keep all URLs set by `history` to one level deep, so `a/b/c` becomes `a-b-c`. All the stuff I've googled on the history API shows only one-level-deep URLs, so maybe this is common
2. Add a `base` tag to the site's `<head>` (`<base "href=http://example.com/" target="_blank">`

Comment: "Note that the absolute paths are even worse, in that the XHR fetches don't even use DocumentRoot (bar) any more." — That's impossible. Relative URLs (including ones with absolute paths) are resolved by the client. The DocumentRoot is used by the server.

Comment: Are you confusing DocumentRoot with "The URL of the original HTML document"?

Comment: Hi @Quentin: `DocumentRoot` is the real Apache `DocumentRoot` from the `httpd.conf` file on the server (which I wrote myself, and I set it to `/var/www/bar`). The comments above come from the client console log on Firefox; the `XHR` entry actually shows directory `bar` in the relative case, and not the absolute case. Yes, I was surprised as well; I wouldn't have expected Firefox to know about it.

Comment: Actually, I suppose the confusing thing is that the relative path shows `bar` at all, and the console message appears to be equating `foo.com` with `/var/www` and then showing `foo.com/bar`. So, maybe it would be more correct to say that the absolute case is better. Anyway, they're both wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the history state [will change the document's *URL*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#history-1) and thus its [`baseURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) if there is no other things that did already change it, like a `<base>` element.

So all future network requests will indeed be made from this new base URI.

To workaround that, you can manually set back the baseURI after you changed you history state,

```js
console.log( document.baseURI ); // /js

history.pushState(null, null, '/foo');
console.log( document.baseURI ); // /foo

// manually set document's baseURI via <base>
const base = document.createElement('base');
base.href = 'bar';
document.head.append(base);
console.log( document.baseURI ); // /bar
```

[As a jsfiddle for users facing StackSnippet's null origined iframes restrictions](https://jsfiddle.net/3bk75hqm/1/)

Or you could even just append this <base> element only once in your document from the first page load.